# In JDK 1.4 API, how do I encrypt a user password that the user entered in a text box?

Tags: encryption, passwords, java

I need to encrypt the password the user enters in a text box on the UI, save it, and then decrypt it when the getPassword() method is called.

What is the correct JDK 1.4 API I should use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just trying to obscure the password in the text box, or do you need to encrypt it, and if you are encrypting it, where are you keeping the encrypted password ultimately?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the quick responses. I need to encrypt the password storing it in the memory, and then decrypt it when calling the getter method. Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that this amounts to obscuring the data, since you will have to keep the key in memory as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example here using Java 1.4 Crypto interface for MD5 encryption:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#HmacEx

Blowfish:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#BlowKeyEx

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption system, it is only for hashing. which is not reversible. which means that it is irrelevant here. Blowfish, on the other hand ...

Comment: hello, what is the correct API to use then?  I need to encrypt the password storing it, and then decrypt it when calling the getter method.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Laurent: njzk2 is correct, but MD5 is what Unix uses. You take the password and MD5 it, and store it somewhere. When the user logs in again, let them enter a password, MD5 it, and compare it to what you have in the database.
If they are equal - the password is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure you passwords, you'll may want to use a Hash algorithm like MD5 or SHA1. You don't want to decrypt the stored password to compare it with the one provided on a login but rather hash the provided password and compare the Hashs

here some documentation on the methods you can use to hash :
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java

Answer (score 0):

Just use Cipher with the "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" mechanism (in getInstance()). You can use a 128 bit (16 byte) AES key created using SecretKeySpec (this is already a key!). Higher bitrates will require unlimited encryption policy files to be installed. As I noted as remark, please note that this is only obscuring the data, since the key will need to be stored with the application - so people that know what to do can retrieve both the password and key and decrypt the information outside of the application.

If you store multiple passwords with the same key, make sure you generate and store a separate random IV per password. The advise in this last paragraph is more to let you know how to encrypt stuff correctly since it is easier to obtain the key than to decrypt the data without it anyway.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if using code obfuscation together with a rather random XORring is not a better way to obscure passwords. I mean, a call to Cipher.getInstance() and the string of the mechanism is rather standing out. But then we get into DRM-like schemes anyway.